# My controller doesn't recognize the value inside ng-model

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-model

heres my root:

```
 .when('/form', {
        templateUrl:'../MyApp/Inventaire/tmpl/inventaire.html',
        controller: 'inventaireCtrl'
    })
```

My problem is, when I set a scope variable in my controller I can't access to it in my view, for example:
if i set `$scope.myVariable='text'` I can't access to it in my view like that:`{{myVariable}}` it works fine, but when I do it in my view I can't access to it im my controller example:

```
<p>Select a car:</p>

<select ng-model="selectedCar">
    <option ng-repeat="x in cars" value="{{x.model}}">{{x.model}}</option>
</select>

<h1>You selected: {{selectedCar}}</h1>
```

controller:

```
  $scope.cars = [
        {model : "Ford Mustang", color : "red"},
        {model : "Fiat 500", color : "white"},
        {model : "Volvo XC90", color : "black"}
    ];
```

selectedCar is undefined

Comment: are you getting any errors in console ?

Comment: No errors...........

Comment: Can you please share all of your code and not just the snippets. This will likely be a naming typo.

Comment: Your code works well... https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/7vaqbqvo/